# Let $f(x,y) = \sin{(x-y)}$, $x = r\cos{θ}$, $y = r\sin{θ}$ find $df/dθ$ and $d^2f/dr^2$

Tags: partial-derivative, chain-rule

Let $f(x,y) = \sin{(x-y)}$, $x = r\cos{\theta}$, $y = r\sin{\theta}$ find $\frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d}θ}$ and $\frac{\text{d}^2f}{\text{d}r^2}$

Using chain rule I got:

$$\frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d}\theta}=\cos(x-y)(-r\sin(\theta))-\cos(x-y)(r\cos(\theta))$$

Which I believe gives me the answer of:

$$\frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d}θ} = -r\cos{(x-y)}(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)$$

---

On part II I'm much less confident but to start I plugged in:

$$x = r\cos(\theta) {\text{ and }} y = r\sin(\theta)$$

Which produced:

$$\cos(r\cos(\theta)-r\sin(\theta))(\cos(\theta)-\sin(\theta)$$

Taking the partial derivative w/ respect to $r$ of that produced:

$$\frac{\text{d}^2f}{\text{d}r^2} = -\sin(r\cos(\theta)-r\sin(\theta))(\cos(\theta)-\sin(\theta))$$

Is this correct? If not could you give me a hint about where I messed up? Thanks!

Comment: This is not a site for homework help. We're happy to offer constructive criticism of approaches and thought processes, but are most certainly not a tutoring service.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I'm struggling with a very difficult subject and have a test on Tuesday, I also work full time during the hours that my school's tutoring center is open and cannot afford to hire a tutor and very few are willing to work at midnight. I'm looking for help and this is the only place that I have gotten any help. Trust me I thoroughly exhaust YouTube and other sites before asking here. I've learned more from the gracious responses on this site than I have from my Calc III professor. How would you like me to format my questions in the future to avoid inconveniencing you?

Comment: Please show your work and ask about approaches and other directions you could have taken, and your own thoughts about your work - what you were confident about, what you were uncertain about.

Comment: Edited it to include your suggestions

Comment: Without walking this through and just looking at the work you've provided, the immediate suggestion I have that I give everyone in your position: be *very* granular about your work, and document every step; it's only OK to skip steps when you know what you're doing so intuitively that you can do it blindfolded. Your first step here will be to convert $f$ from a function in terms of $x$ and $y$ to one in terms of $r$ and $\theta$ - once you have that, circle it in sharpie and work off that.

Comment: Some comments here: 1) Try to express the terms symbolically before calculation, i.e., $$\frac{df}{d\theta}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{dx}{d\theta}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{dy}{d\theta}$$, so as to make things clearer for yourself and the marker. 2) Part 1 is correct, but it'll be better if it is first expressed symbolically.

Answer (score 1):

Part I is correct.

For Part II, as @Did mentioned, the $\cos(r(\cos\theta-\sin\theta))$ term is actually a composed function in the form  $$s(r)=u(v(r))$$ So $$\frac{df}{dr}=A\cdot s(r)$$

where $$u(t)=\cos(t)$$  $$v(r)=r(\cos\theta-\sin\theta)$$ $$A=\cos\theta-\sin\theta$$

The derivative is thus given by
\begin{align}
\frac{d^2f}{dr^2}&=A\frac{ds}{dr}\\&=A\frac{ds}{du}\cdot\frac{dv}{dr}\\&=Ar\sin(r(\cos\theta-\sin\theta))\cdot(\cos\theta-\sin\theta)\\&=r\sin(r(\cos\theta-\sin\theta))\cdot(\cos\theta-\sin\theta)^2
\end{align}